# Function error with numbers and decimal point in parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, import, parameters

I am new to Python any help would be appreciated.

There is a red squiggly line underneath the parameter.("0123456789.txt")

This is my function.

```
def write_countries_capitals_to_file(0123456789.txt):
```

```
def main():
    """
    Calling functions.
    """


    write_countries_capitals_to_file("0123456789.txt")
```

I'm confused as to why i'm getting an error. I know if I place a letter in front of the numbers the numbers get grayed out. But I need it to work how it is displayed.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The function parameter has to be a variable name,.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on defining functions.

Comment: " But I need it to work how it is displayed." what do you *think* that would do? What you wrote doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga  your really smart. I thought to ask here actually my teacher actually made a mistake on the info he gave us I just got notified. If your gonna comment make sense and give some good feedback.

Comment: @Hudson I *am* giving you good feedback. A well-formed question would include *the expected behavior*. See [ask] and the [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an issue with variable naming. In Python, variables have to follow the following rules:

1. The characters in variable names must be alphanumeric or the underscore (`_`) character.
2. Variable names must be one word
3. Variable names cannot start with a number

Parameter naming rules are the same as variable names (since parameters are essentially local variables). Since the name `1234567890.txt` has a character (`.`) which which is not alphanumeric and is not the underscore character (Rule 1), and the variable name starts with a number (Rule 3), then the variable name is invalid.